# Number Theory: Problem with proofs

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

There are two propositions in the chapter of Number Theory in my book, the proofs of which I am having trouble to understand.

[image]

[image]

**For Proposition 3**

I cannot understand the proof from "Therefore ..." in the third line. I was thinking that maybe "$m-l$ divides $k$" will be "$m-l$ divides $n$". Also, is $k/d$ an integer?
Also, can someone please give an example to clarify this theorem?

**For Proposition 4**

What does $f(x) \in Z[x]$ mean? Why are the third brackets used?

I cannot understand how "By proposition 2, $a_ja^j \equiv b_jb^j$ (mod $n$)...".
Can someone please explain?

Comment: I think the book has a typo and instead of $m-l$ divides $k$" it is supposed to be "$d$ divides $k$".  That fits with $(m-l)d = kn\implies m-l = \frac kd n$ which assumes $\frac kd$ is an integer.... on the other hand, that is one heck of a type to make!

Answer (score 4):

For proposition 3, I agree with fleablood's assessment in a comment above that this is probably a typo.

For proposition $4$, note that the thing you're asking about appears in a parenthesis, following the abbreviation "i.e.". That means that even without knowing what "$f\in \Bbb Z[x]$" means, we can infer that it's merely an alternative formulation of whatever came before, namely that $f$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients.

To actually answer the question, given a ring $R$, the notation $R[x]$ means "the ring (or set) of polynomials with coefficients in $R$". So $\Bbb Z[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients. And $f\in \Bbb Z[x]$ means exactly that $f$ is an element of this ring.

As for why we use the brackets there? That's just convention. You could have $\Bbb Z(x)$ as well, but that usually means the ring (or set) of *rational functions* with integer coefficients.

Finally, the "by proposition 2" thing, note that proposition 2 states that if we have a product of two things, and we change one of the factors to a congruent factor, the product is unchanged modulo $n$. So $$a_ja^j = a_ja^{j-1}\cdot a\equiv a_ja^{j-1}b\pmod n$$
So we can swap one $a$ for a $b$. Now just swap the other $j-1$ $a$'s for $b$'s, one by one as proposition 2 says you're allowed to do, and finally you reach $a_jb^j$.

Comment: heck of a typo to make;  and heck of a way to define and introduce notation (as an aside inside a parenthesis).  If anything it should go the other way: "Let $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x] (i.e. $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients)".  This book isn't winning me over.

Comment: @fleablood When I learned complex analysis, the book had enough strategically placed typos that I gave up and used wikipedia to learn the theorems instead. And the educational value of wikipedia math articles is not always the greatest, as they mostly seem like reference works. So I know how it is.

Comment: Shouldn't you write "$f(x)\in \Bbb Z[x]$" instead of "$f\in \Bbb Z[x]$" since $f$ denotes the set just like R (relation) denotes the set?

Comment: @MrAP it's a matter of what you want to convey. $f$ is the name of the polynomial. $f(x)$ is the expression that defines the polynomial. At least that's how I think about it. 
$\Bbb Z$ is the ring / set of integers, $\Bbb Z[x]$ is the ring / set of polynomials with integer coefficients. Also, $R$ isn't a relation here. I did say "ring". Like $\Bbb Z$, or $\Bbb R$. If that isn't a term you've come across yet, then I am sorry for confusing you.

Comment: By $R$ I meant the a relation. $R:A\to B$ is a subset of $A\times B$. So similarly $f:A\to B$ should also be a subset of $A\times B$ since a function is a relation. So $f$ denotes a set which represents a function. And normally we write that an element belongs to a set. Here as you have written, it would mean that a set belongs to another set which is normally not the case. That is what I am trying to express.

Comment: @MrAP First of all, a set can certainly belong to another set, there is nothing wrong with that (particularly, even though functions are sets, you can have sets of functions). Second, $f$ isn't a set, and it is not a function. It is a polynomial. The _expression_ of that polynomial, like $x^2$, or $3x^7-5x^4+3$, or whatever it happens to be, is what I call $f(x)$. Then you have the _function_ which takes an integer $n$ as input and gives back $f(n)$. I would probably call that function $f$ as well, as there aren't many better options. But polynomials are not functions.

Comment: I don't understand how "proposition 2 states that if we have a product of two things, and we change one of the factors to a congruent factor, the product is unchanged modulo n". Can you please explain? Where does proposition 2 state that. I am very confused.

Comment: @MrAP Proposition 2 states that when it says $a_1b_1\equiv a_2b_2$. Actually, proposition 2 allows for changing _both_ factors ($a_1$ into $a_2$ and $b_1$ into $b_2$), but if $a_1$ and $a_2$ are _equal_, then certainly they are congruent, so changing only one of the factors is still within what the proposition proposes.

Answer (score 3):

I think the book made a typo and it isn't $m-l$ that divides $k$ (I don't see that as even true) but that $d$ divides $k$.

This follow as $d$ divides $kn$ but is relatively prime to $n$ so $d$ must divide $k$.

And hence, yes, $\frac kd$ is an integer, for which we conclude $m-l \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

Note:  This will *not* be true if $a, b, n$ will have a common divisor (other than $1$).  Consider $8 \equiv 20 \mod 12$ but $2\equiv 5 \mod 12$ is .... wrong.  (Although $2 \equiv 5 \pmod 3$.....)

--- I empathize.  For a typo that is a *doozy* to make and utter *destroys* the intent of the proof.

....

$\mathbb Z[x]$ means the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients.

So $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ means "Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: $(m-l)d=kn$ implies that $d$ divides $k$ and also $n$ divides $m-l$. Correct?

Comment: ***IF*** $d$ and $n$ are relatively prime (i.e. $\gcd(d,n)=1$) then $d$ and $n$ have no factors in common.  So if $(m-l)d = kn$ then $d$ divides $kn$.  But as $d$ and $n$ have *nothing* in common, that means $d$ divides $k$.  Likewise that means $n$ divides $(m-l)d$ but $n$ and $d$ have nothing in common so $n$ divides $m-l$..... BTW "$n$ divides $A$" and "$A\equiv 0 \pmod n$" mean the exact same thing. And "$n$ divides $m-l$" and "$m\equiv l \pmod n$" and "$m-l \equiv 0 \pmod n$" all mean the same thing.